# Returning parametrized class in Swift

Tags: swift

I don't really know how to name it correctly, but I want to achieve this:

I want to be able to return a class in Swift, from a function that takes 1 argument. That one argument should be used as a value inside that class, so if some other piece of code instantiates that class it is unaware of that argument.

Let me try and explain it in some pseudo code (that doesn't work obviously)

```
protocol MyProtocol : class {
    init()
    func getImage() -> UIImage
}


func classBuilder(_ image:UIImage) -> MyProtocol.self {

    return class InternalClass : MyProtocol {

        private var theImage:UIImage!

        init() {
            self.theImage = image
        }

        func getImage() -> UIImage {
            return theImage
        }
    }
}

TheClass = classBuilder(UIImage.init(named:"test"))

theInstance = TheClass()

theImage = theInstance.getImage()
```

This actual example can be solved otherwise, but it's to keep things simple and to try and make it understandable.

I want to be able to do this so code (that I don't own) can instantiate classes using an empty constructor (simply `init`) because it's the only constructor they support, while allowing me to customise the class somehow without having to hardcode all the possible images inside that class. I can't pass instances, only classes. (like the `MKMapView.register` methods)

You can do stuff like this in Javascript. Just wondering if Swift allows it too, as the only info I find is all about generics, and they handle types, not values. I can't define a class by doing `MyClass<someImage>.self` or something along those lines.

Comment: You cannot dynamically define a class in Swift. You might be looking for a dependency injection. If the code is not yours, you might need to write a wrapper. Hard to tell with this toy example.

Answer (score 0):

The possible approach to solve this, or close to what you tried to describe, is by separation *public interface + factory function* from private implementation.

So it can look like below. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
// public interface
public protocol ImageProvider {
    func getImage() -> UIImage
}

// factory function providing opaque implementation
public func createImageProvider(_ image: UIImage?) -> some ImageProvider {
    // here you can decide which implementor to choose to return
    return InternalClass(image: image)
}

// private implementation of public interface
private class InternalClass : ImageProvider {

    private var theImage:UIImage!

    init(image: UIImage? = UIImage()) {
        self.theImage = image
    }

    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        return theImage
    }
}

// usage
let image = createImageProvider(UIImage(named:"test")).getImage()
```

Comment: The problem is that the code which is not mine wants a class type as parameter, to do its instantiation internally

Comment: @JorisMans, then you have to use bridged objective-c for that case.

Comment: Ok. I'll figure out something else then. This is becoming too much hassle. Thanks for the help.